# NoClassDefFoundError of org.apache.taglibs.standard.util.XmlUtil when deployed

Tags: java, jsp, wildfly, jstl

I created a dynamic web project which include a jsp. I want to use the jstl in it. So I copy the standard.jar and jstl.jar to WEB-INF/lib. Then add below code to the jsp.

```
<%@ taglib prefix="fn" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>
```

I didn't add these two jars to Java Build Path or include them in the deployment assembly, but when I run it in eclipse it work fine. Then after I export it as war and deploy to my wildfly 11 server. It has error as below

```
Exception handling request to /SAP_SD_QUERY/: javax.servlet.ServletException: 
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.apache.taglibs.standard.util.XmlUtil
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:356)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletHandler.handleRequest(ServletHandler.java:85)
    at ... 
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class 
org.apache.taglibs.standard.util.XmlUtil
    at org.apache.taglibs.standard.tlv.JstlBaseTLV.validate(JstlBaseTLV.java:154)
    at org.apache.taglibs.standard.tlv.JstlCoreTLV.validate(JstlCoreTLV.java:97)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.TagLibraryInfoImpl.validate(TagLibraryInfoImpl.java:565)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:347)
    ... 40 more
```

I also tried including jars in deployment assembly and modify the web.xml with below

```
<taglib>
<taglib-uri>http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core</taglib-uri>
<taglib-location>/WEB-INF/c.tld</taglib-location>
</taglib>
```

and it has error

```
ERROR [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-7) WFLYUT0074: 
Could not find TLD 
 /WEB-INF/c.tld
```

How to fix it? Anyone help? Thx.

Comment: WildFly is a normal JEE server. It already ships with JSTL out the box. Please remove all JSTL JARs and certainly that taglib entry and retry. Manually installing JSTL JARs is only necessary in non-JEE servers such as Tomcat or Jetty. Manually registering taglib in web.xml is never necessary. It only indicates that wrong JARs have been used.

Comment: @BalusC Thx. I removed all jars from web-inf/libs and taglib in web.xml. Then I remove <%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>   from jsp and I can open the page now. But if I remove <%@ taglib prefix="fn" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions"%>  also and it has error and jsp can't open.

Comment: I didn't mean to remove the taglib declaration from JSP. Just keep it in. When I said "taglib enter" I was referring to the `<taglib>` XML entry in `web.xml`. That one is absolutely an illegal approach to the problem.

Comment: @BalusC. I add back the taglib in JSP and still not working. Is this something related to WildFly configuration? I checked Module folder and JSTL  jars do exist.

Comment: You need to exactly define "not working".

Comment: @BalusC.Same error log as posted in the question.

Comment: Most probably you've also manually installed JAXB via the webapp instead of utilizing the server-provided one.